# Disable LinkedIn mobile application from displaying notification number badge on the app icon

Tags: android, push, linkedin

Is it possible to disable the LinkedIn mobile application for Android from displaying notification number badge on the app icon?

[image]

I don’t want the number badge in the top right corner to appear. I am using the latest version of the application.

Answer (score 1):

On your device, navigate to Settings -> Application Manager -> All -> Settings -> Show System and then BadgeProvider should appear. Within these preferences, select Force Stop, then Disable.

Or download package disabler pro... it 1.99 but works.  Requires a Samsung I think.